# Can Rails do something equivalent to PHP's json_decode (as seen used in this example)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I've been trying to practice parsing JSON data returned from API calls. I've stumbled upon [this example](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples) showing how to use RottenTomatoes API in PHP. Is there a similar functionality in Rails to "map" this data in to "objects"? Making this sort of thing possible:

```
@movies.each do |movie|
  puts movie.title
end
```

[Here is an example](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movies_Search) of the data return I'm expecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveSupport::JSON has a decode method:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_string)
```

See here for a nice writeup:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/

For your example:

```
data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_string)
data["movies"].each{|m| puts m}
```

Just as an example.

Comment: This returns a Hash, which is not what I'm ultimately after.

Comment: It returns a hash, however you can grab the movies key and iterate over the movies from there.

Comment: Okay, I guess I was looking for something to do "that" for me. But looking it at it now, thats really quite easy. Dont know how I've broken my head on this for so many hours :)

Comment: I know what you mean, however Ruby tends to lessen the frustration. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Crack?

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/04/01/crack-the-easiest-way-to-parse-xml-and-json/

```
require 'httparty'
require 'crack'

response = HTTParty::get("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=XXX")
@movies = Crack::JSON.parse(response.body)
```